# PostGIS - Nearest Neighbour Join to sum values

Tags: postgis, nearest-neighbor

I have a table of polygons T1 and a second table of points P1

Each point has a value

I want to sum the values of P1 for each T1, with P1 being the closest set of points to T1

At the moment the only way I can see to do this is compute a nearest neighbour for each P1 from the T1 table. Then having done this compute the sum. It seems inefficient as P1 contains millions of rows compared to T1 which has a few hundred thousand.

Is there a better approach? It is critical that points in P1 are not allocated to multiple polygons in T1. This is current approach

```
SELECT distinct on(B.id) B.id,   
   sum("count") OVER (PARTITION BY B.id) as point_count   
FROM P1
INNER JOIN LATERAL (SELECT id FROM T1 ORDER BY P1.wkb_geometry <-> 
T1.wkb_geometry LIMIT 1) B 
ON TRUE
```

Comment: if the respective points are not spatially *within* those polygons, or within (unambiguous) proximity of them, a *(K) Nearest Neighbor* (just like you outlined) search with a `LATERAL` join and the `<->` *KNN* operator on properly indexed geom columns would be the proper (and I dare say only) way; assign polygon ids to each point and sum over those ids.

Comment: Yep, that is basically what I am doing now

Comment: maybe try with `SELECT B.id, SUM(P1.id) AS point_count FROM ... GROUP BY B.id` for better performance on large tables.